# cPanel: how to access non registered domains?

Tags: virtualhost

I'm learning to use cpanel whm on a brand new dedicated server which address is like kb4343.domain.com . I created an account (say "example").

I would like that if people access http://kb4343.domain.com, they see the website created under account "example".

How can i do that? And if it is not possible, where should i put the website in cpanel file directory so that it become the "live" website for that address ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://kb4343.domain.com/~cpanelusername

where cpanelusername is the username of the cpanel account you want to visit

NOTE: you need to have mod_userdir protection disabled for the accessing domain (eg kb4343.domain.com) or completely disabled for it to work

ALSO: if you use an app like wordpress that auto 301's to the desired url you will need to override it to the http://kb4343.domain.com/~cpanelusername type url via the web apps configuration otherwise it wont work

you want a different website/page to come up if you load that hostname? then you need to chuck the files in: /usr/local/apache/htdocs, bear in mind this will come up for any site that points at the server but isnt setup in whm or if they access via the IP without the ~username url added

Comment: Thanks. So, there is no way to map the ip address directly to a given account's domain localroot?

Comment: not unless its a dedicated IP - if its a dedicated IP for the site, loading the IP will load that site

Comment: well, the server has a dedicated IP. Since it's the only site that will be hosted there (with 2 subdomains), I suppose i could do that.

Comment: if its the only ip on the server, cpanel wont work like that, if its an extra IP then sure just move the account to the dedicated IP, however anyone visiting the other ip will still get cpanel default page

Comment: OK i'll stick to your suggest andswer. Thanks a lot for your time Anthony!

Comment: Related question: is there a way i can access my subdomains via a similar http://kb4343.domain.com/~cpanelusername address ?